# C++ divisors code with loops

Tags: c++, loops

I have a problem on **coderforces** that called **divisors**.

I believe that I had solved it, but it gives me a **time limit exceeded** error so I had tried my best to make it shorter but still the same error.

In the problem I have to give how many divisors the number should have.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    long long  t, x;
    int res = 2;
    cin >> t;

    for (int j = 0; j < t; j++){
        cin >> x;
        for (int i = 2; i <= x / 2; i++){
            if (x%i == 0){
                res++;
            }
        }
        cout << res << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example input should be:

> 3
>
> 12
>
> 7
>
> 36

The output should be:

> 6
>
> 2
>
> 9

Comment: So, what is actually your question?

Comment: @MohamedMoanis i want to make the code shorter in loops to avoid the time limit exceed but i don't know how

Comment: So do you have to print how many divisors each number from 1 to `t` has?

Comment: @Polb **t** is the test cases and i have to print how many divisors number **x** has from **1** to **x**

Comment: I guess you need to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110344/algorithm-to-calculate-the-number-of-divisors-of-a-given-number)

Comment: The factors for 12 are 1,2,3,4,6,12? for 36 1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "split" your inside loop (the one that counts the divisors of the current number) in two separate case, based on whether the current number is odd or even: if it is odd, then you only have to check the division with odd numbers, starting from 3.

Anyway, you can optimeze the inner loop a bit more by checking only the numbers from 2 to `floor(sqrt(x))`. If a number `x` is divisible by `i`, then it will also be divisible by `x / i`, so instead checking the numbers from 2 to `x / 2`, look only until `(int) sqrt(x)` (it is not absolutely necessary to cast the result of `sqrt`, since `i` is `int`).

The code for the inner loop might look like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= (int)sqrt(x); i++) {
    if (x % i == 0)
        res += 2;
}
```

Comment: i think i understand what you are saying but how do i look until **(int) sqrt(x/2)** i didn't understand this one

Comment: I added a code snippet to make things a bit clearer.

Comment: @MostafaIbrahem My bad, I typed something wrong, the loop goes until `sqrt(x)`, not `sqrt(x / 2)` (corrected that).

Comment: i didn't understand what you meant by counting until `(int) sqrt(x/2)` and how to use it sorry i'm beginner

Comment: i made the loop until it goes to `sqrt(x)` but it output **4** instead of **6** when i enter **12**

Comment: It means iterating through all the numbers from 2 to `(int)sqrt(x)` (in our examples) and translated into code it looks like the `for` loop in the answer.

Comment: Let's see... initially `res` is 2. We start iterating from 2. `(int)sqrt(12)` is 3. So our `i` will only go through 2 and 3. For 2: `12 % 2 == 0` so now `res` is incremented by 2. Now `res` is 4. Next, `i` is 3. `12 % 3 == 0` so now `res` is now incremented by 2 again, `res == 6`. Are you sure you reset `res` to 2 for each number?

Comment: the number 12 and most numbers worked but when i enter **36** it prints **10** can you please tell me why? it should be 9 i think

Comment: This happens because sqrt(36) is a perfect square, so the algorithm is counting 6 two times, one from `i = 6` and the other from `i = 36 / 6`, which yields exactly 6. You can add an extra check for perfect squares, like `if (sqrt(x) == (int)sqrt(x) && i == sqrt(x)) res++; else res += 2;`

Answer (score 0):

First your code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; // poluting namespace
int main(){
long long  t, x; // <------- EVIL use int64_t if that is what you want.
int res = 2; // is never reset is that your intent?
             // what if x == 1???
cin >> t;

for (int j = 0; j < t; j++){ // comparing an int32_t with an int64_t ...
    cin >> x; // stream has seldom been accused of being fast but is not likely to be the problem.

    for (int i = 2; i <= x / 2; i++){ // as already suggested stop at sqrt(x) or see below.
        if (x%i == 0){ // % is a costly operation.
            res++;
        }
    }
    cout << res << endl; // search for endl considered dangerous. use '\n' instead.
}
return 0;
}
```

EDIT: removed wrong code.

so what you can use from this is don't use `std::endl` as it flushes the output after each write use '\n' instead.

Comment: @Surf cant understand it quietly i use G++11

Comment: Added the header file for int64_t.

Comment: @MostafaIbrahem Which part of it is problematic?

Comment: Give an example input and output so we know what we are trying to solve.

Comment: Ah that makes it much more clear as this version gives 1*2*2*3 or 4 factors.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you really need to improve the loop itself. What you should do is make use of mathematical properties of numbers, specifically of prime numbers. You should only loop up to the square root of the number. (See this question: [Optimize calculation of prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649854/optimize-calculation-of-prime-numbers)).

Here is my version of the code using the square root:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long inputs;
    cin >> inputs;

    for(long long j = 0 ; j < inputs ; ++j) {
        int divisors = 2;
        long long current, maxdiv;
        cin >> current;
        maxdiv = sqrt(current);

        for(long long i = 2 ; i <= maxdiv ; ++i)
            if(current % i == 0)
                divisors += 2;

        // If the square root is a divisor, we added one divisor too many above.
        if(maxdiv * maxdiv == current)
            --divisors;

        cout << divisors << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I also optimized the output by using "\n" instead of std::cout to avoid flushing the output every time.

Comment: No problem. If this answer worked for you please consider accepting it.